# OAuth 2 can i use Post Form Response and PCKE at the same time?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am trying to secure an SPA, now there is recommendations to use PCKE which is fine, there is also a lot of articles which suggest use post form response, however if the server returns a html form then how would i add the pcke verifier?

Answer (score 0):

you don't, post form uses implicit flow so pcke isn't used